# JSPC: jsp:attribute must be the subelement of a standard or custom action

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm using Maven to precompile my JSPs in my webapp. I'm using quite a few custom tags but one of them chokes Apache's JSP compiler.

The relevant part of the JSP is this:

```
<jb:contentChanger containerId="${previewImageContainer}">
  <jsp:attribute name="content">
    <div id="${previewImageContainer}"> 
      <jsp:include page="../inc/fa_zoom.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="picNUrl" value="${PicNUrl}"/>
       <jsp:param name="picXUrl" value="${largeZoomImgUrl}.jpg"/>  
      </jsp:include>
    </div>
  </jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:body>
     <jb:ajaxPopupLinkMedia href="${mediaURL}" width="660px" height="675px">
       <img src="${morePicPreview}" alt="${product.name}" border="0" style="width:40px; height:40px;"/>
     </jb:ajaxPopupLinkMedia>
  </jsp:body>
</jb:contentChanger>
```

JSPC complains that `jsp:attribute must be the subelement of a standard or custom action`. But looking at my code `jsp:attribute` *is* a subelement of my custom action `jb:contentChanger`.

What is also suspcious that it works if I copy the JSP into the running Tomcat. No complaints there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have included the definition for jb:contentChanger?

Comment: I actually found the answer to this problem: in my pom.xml I set the taglib's jar scope to "runtime" which is true, but of course caused the compile time error I experienced.